# How to get stack frame in 64-bit application in IDAPython?

Tags: python, ida

In 86-bit pe/elf this code works:

```
ea=ScreenEA()
stack = GetFrame(ea)
size = GetStrucSize(stack)
names = []
for i in xrange(size):
    n = GetMemberName(stack, i)
    if n and not n in names:
        names.append(n)
print names
```

but in 64-bit applications value in 'stack' variable is invalid and get exception:

```
Expected an ea_t type
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\IDA Pro Advanced Edition v6.1\python\idaapi.py", line 373, in IDAPython_ExecScript
    execfile(script, g)
  File "F:/123.py", line 11, in <module>
    size = GetStrucSize(stack)
  File "\IDA Pro Advanced Edition v6.1\python\idc.py", line 4760, in GetStrucSize
    return idaapi.get_struc_size(sid)
  File "\IDA Pro Advanced Edition v6.1\python\idaapi.py", line 25013, in get_struc_size
    return _idaapi.get_struc_size(*args)
TypeError: Expected an ea_t type
```

How can i get frame in 64-bit?

Versions:
IDA 6.1
IDAPython 1.5
Python 2.6.6

Comment: Hm, maybe it's a bug of old versions.